# How to fill data in the table when using xml datasource in jasper reports using java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I tried finding the solutions but I could not find any,and even some of my tables are not visible in the report. When designing the report using *iReport* GUI designer and filling the data using *Java*.

I have taken *jrxml* file from following location and and have taken an xml data source

```
    try {
        JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds = new JRXmlDataSource("D:\\Bhvika\\InputData11.xml","/xdata/rows/row");

        Map params = new HashMap();
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D:\\Bhvika\\jasperRpt3Mod11.jasper", params,jrxmlds);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "D:\\Bhvika\\jasperRpt3Mod11.pdf");

        JasperViewer.viewReport(print);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

By doing this i am getting a report where every field is getting populated but in the table there no value is coming.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. 
Can you highlight what you did first and be specific about it ?
Do remember to post code and data examples to help the question be informative enough for members to answer. 
Please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on this.

Comment: I designed my report using the Ireport and the Jrxml that was genrated I gave that path to the Fill manager, and the inputdatasource that is xml was passes into the  JRXmlDataSource along with tha xpath in Ireport and in JasperExportManager the PDF which you want to genrate and with which name is passed.